# Searching for a blank cell in a column of merged cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet where Column A consists of a number of merged cells with data. I need to write a formula that can identify the end of that column of merged cells, in other words, I need to identify the first blank cell in that column. The formulas that I have experimented with get confused by the fact that I am dealing with merged cells. I understand now that the data of a group of merged cells is kept at the top (top left corner if we are talking about a range spreading over one column) with the rest of the cells considered to be blank. Any suggestions please as to how I can identify the end of my column of merged cells? Many thanks.

Tried to look for blank cells but formulas get confused by merged cells.

Comment: [`Range.MergeArea`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.mergearea) may be useful.

Comment: Why don't you share one of your (not working) codes explaining what is wrong with it so someone can share a solution with the necessary corrections applied? You can [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74289909/edit) at any time.

Comment: Working with merged cells is a really, really bad idea.

Comment: Have you tried `Set FirstCell = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)`? I'm surprised, too.

Comment: The code I used and did not work is the following: 

i=1
Do Until Cells(i, "A") = ""
    i = i + 1
Loop

Cells(i, "A").Select



Row 1 are my headings, then cells in column A are merged. It will read the data on cell A2, then stop at A3 thinking it is blank (cells A2 to A8, then A9 to A20 etc, are all merged, sizes vary)